# React router doesn't route properly with firebase authentication

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, react-router, react-router-dom

first of all I'm not an expert in react so this question may seem silly.
I have a react page that has a loginAdmin and an AdminDashboard, when an admin is logged in it redirect him to the admin dashboard! for now this is ok.
***EDIT***
What's coming is correct and both are solutions, but the problem is they both don't work until I update something in my code, it's probably getting the auth information from firebase delay is causing the problem!

The problem happens when the admin goes back to the login page, I want to prevent the page from showing if he's already logged in!
For this problem I've tried two ways for solving it, but both doesn't work until I update something.
Here's what I've tried!

First attempt: ***LOGIN***

```
const [isLoggedIn, setLogin] = React.useState(false);
React.useEffect(()=>{
  checkIfLogged();
},[]);
const checkIfLogged=()=>{
  const auth= getAuth();
  const user = auth.currentUser; //Using firebase auth
  if (user){   
   setLogin(true);
   console.log(user); // This is null until updating something then it prints the user informations
  else setLogin(false); 
}
```

And then in the rendering I've put the conditionnal rendering :

```
{isLoggedIn? <AdminDashboard />: <LoginAdmin />}
```

If an admin is Logged and go to the login page, the login page shows until if and only if I update something in the code then it redirects to the adminDashboard.

My second attempt was with the routing, as mentioned in [React router V6](https://gist.github.com/mjackson/d54b40a094277b7afdd6b81f51a0393f#route-composition-in-react-router-v6)

I've tried adding the RequireAuth in my App.js :

```
<Router>

<Routes>
<Route path='/admindashboard' element={<AdminDashboard} />
<Route path='/loginadmin' element={
      <RequireAuth redirectTo='/admindashboard'>
        <LoginAdmin />
      </RequireAuth>
      } />
</Routes>

</Router>
```

```
function RequireAuth({ children, redirectTo }) {
  let isAuthenticated = getAuth().currentUser;
  console.log(isAuthenticated); //Null until some update!
  return isAuthenticated ? <Navigate to ={redirectTo} /> : children;
}
```

And also doesn't work until I make some update, it's like the page is Loading before getting the auth informations ready!
Any help?

Comment: I think the problem has to do with `const user = auth.currentUser;` What is the value of user on first page load?

Comment: You can use two methods for save and read user data using eg. "   window.localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(res));"   Create global method "isAuth"  for reading data from localStoreage.

Comment: Ideally you need to implement an Auth Context . It's global state that holds a user object. Once the user has been set in the context, you can navigate your page as you like. When the user logs out, the user creds in the context is removed and it kicks you back to the login page. Each time you refresh the browser, it will trigger the onAuthStateChange method and check if the user is logged in. There are a lot of firebase / Auth context tutorials out there to follow. I have one setup with nextJS on git if you would like to take a look

Comment: @FowotadeBabajide So after the first load the user value is null and that's the problem, as mentioned in the question the problem is timing the auth information are coming after the loading page.

Comment: @RyanZeelie Thanks for the help but I'm fully aware of the Auth Context solution for this problem, but I wanted to do it this way just to avoid using the whole context concept!

Comment: As-written it seems your question is about protecting the "login" route from already authenticated users, i.e. your "The problem happens when the admin goes back to the login page, I want to prevent the page from showing if he's already logged in!". It doesn't look like anything is triggering a component rerender when the auth status changes, *other than* you editing some code and the hot-reloader kicks in. What is `getAuth()`? Can you [edit] the post to include all the relevant authentication and routing code? Can you provide exact reproduction steps that reproduce any issue(s)?

Comment: Based on one of your comments about "way just to avoid using the whole context concept" does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/69950052/8690857 This would be with regards to any asynchronous auth check that needs to happen prior to accessing a route.

Comment: @DrewReese I've edited and added some relevant authentication and routing as requested, even though, as you suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/69950052/17263804 It worked perfectly fine preventing the user from accessing the login page without any hot-reload! thanks for your help!